# Selenium C# IJavaScriptExecutor throws error but JS is fine

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, click

I'm using Selenium C# to test a pretty complex web UI in Internet Explorer 11. As you might know, Selenium's Click() tends to not work in which case inserting a JS click method is necessary.
I'm running the dynamically generated script below using

(IJavaScriptExecutor) driver).ExecuteScript(script).
Here is the script :

```
let iFrame = document.getElementById("dkwframe").contentWindow.document;
let element = iFrame.querySelector("[id*='_ImgLnkNewPage_LinkButtonControl']");
element.click();
```

The script works fine when I execute it directly in the IE console, but when executing with it Selenium I get this :

```
System.InvalidOperationException : Error executing JavaScript (UnexpectedJavaScriptError)
```

The IE console is empty so I don't think it's even trying. Also, switching browser isn't an option.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Note that by calling `.click()` you are no longer simulating a user click and no longer writing an end to end test. The `click` from Javascript simply executes the underlying listener or attached redirection which doesn't validate that a real user will be able to click the targeted element. Regarding you error, `let` is not supported by IE11 and should be replaced by `var`.

Comment: Hello and thanks for the response. I know calling the .click() is not ideal but it's the only solution I've got. As for what I'm clicking I make sure it's a clickable element.
I will try to replace let by var asap!

Comment: No, even replacing let by var doesn't change anything

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the script is being executed before the page is fully loaded ,try to put it in a page ready event ha dler like that

```
window.onload = function() {
    et iFrame = document.getElementById("dkwframe").contentWindow.document;
    let element = iFrame.querySelector("[id*='_ImgLnkNewPage_LinkButtonControl']");
    element.click();
}
```

Or you can check if the fully loaded with :

```
if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
}
```

Comment: Let me know if this helped

Comment: Hello and thanks. Unfortunately, having the window fully loaded and putting the script in a function didn't solve it :/